# TextView.OnEditorActionListener not called

Tags: android

I am adding `setOnEditorActionListener` to an EditText, but why is the listener is not getting triggered?

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initMemoField(findViewById(R.id.memo_edit_text));
    }

    void initMemoField(final EditText editText) {
        editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                Log.d("Main", "Current Text: " + s.toString());
            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
        });
        editText.setOnEditorActionListener((v, actionId, event) -> {
            Log.v("Main", "This listener does not get triggered.");

            if(actionId== EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                Log.v("Main", "Expect to reach here when Keyboard closed.");
                editText.clearFocus();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });

        editText.clearFocus();
    }
```

EditText in layout file:

```
  <EditText
            android:id="@+id/memo_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.30"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:inputType="text|textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:maxLines ="4"
            android:maxLength ="2000"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"/>
```

Complete sample is at: https://gist.github.com/acnvrk/5de5f954c65273349c2ee4835bfe78d2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE` action is not raised when the `EditText` control is defined with input-type `textMultiLine`